# Add simple table with text to screen

Tags: blackberry, tablemodel

How do I add a simple plain table with data to existing screen?

The data is already parsed text from DOM. Can I do it with TableModel? Here's what I have now:

```
TableModel tm = new TableModel();
tm.addRow(doc.getElementsByTagName("id").item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue());
tm.addRow(doc.getElementsByTagName("id").item(1).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue());

final MyScreen screen = new MyScreen();
```

Can I use something like:

```
screen.add(...)
```

Or it should I use something other than the `TableModel` container?

Comment: what is this TableModel class? is it predefined or custom class?

Comment: this is prdefined class,I've found in lib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TableModel` is merely a data model. To display the data, you'll need to use a `Field` that uses the data contained in the `TableModel`. I'd suggest making a custom field that accepts this `TableModel` object. You could also use a `GridFieldManager` and add `LabelField`s to it for each cell of the `TableModel` object.